# How can I use Parallel loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

If I have the following code in Matlab, How can I fix the indexing in st3 matrix in order to perform parallel loop? Thank you

```
n=1;
parfor j=1:10
[~,x1]=compare2Arrays(st1,st2);
    if isempty(x1)
        st3(n)=st4(j);
        n=n+1;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the loops doesn't run in sequence. You cant use `n` like that. Here is the updated code.

```
n=1;
st5=nan(1,10);
parfor j=1:10
[~,x1]=compare2Arrays(st1,st2);
    if isempty(x1)
        st5(j)=st4(j);
    end
end
st3=st5(not(isnan(st5)));
```